# MUI/x-date pickers DatePicker component year view or month view

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, mui-x-data-grid

I would like to modify `MUI` / `x-datepickers` DatePicker component so that:

- when we open a year view or month view the current month or year not be selected with background.
- when we click on it then it should be selected.

So it would have 2 cases

[image: MUI Calendar Condition 1]
[image: MUI Calendar Condition 2]

I haven't found documentation about a prop that can disable it when opening first.